# How to replace all spaces with new lines?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that contains spaces in its headers

```
First Name   Last Name       Average Level Degree   
_________________________________________________
Mike         Lowel           25 
Stan         Wilson          35 
Papa         Peterson        15
```

I need it to look like this

```
 First        Last            Average  
 Name         Name            Level 
                              Degree
 _____________________________________________
 Mike         Lowel           25 
 Stan         Wilson          35 
 Papa         Peterson        15
```

Here is what I tried

```
Sub test()

myString = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value = Replace(myString, " ", CHAR(10))
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").WrapText = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").EntireRow.AutoFit

myString = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("b1").Value
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("b1").Value = Replace(myString, " ", CHAR(10))
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("b1").WrapText = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("b1").EntireRow.AutoFit

End Sub
```

However, it throws an error. In addition, I am not sure how to loop over all letters. Is there any more efficient way. I need those headers to look nice: I need to get the same effect as if I click `Alt+Enter`. Each word should appear on a separate line

Comment: Try `vbNewline` instead of `CHAR(10)`

Comment: or char(10)+char(13)

Comment: @xQbert actually that's Windows-specific. `vbNewLine` is platform-independent.

Comment: *it throws an error* is a totally meaningless problem description unless you include the information about what specific *error* it throws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one line of code:

```
Range("A1:C1").Replace " ",vblf
```

In the range it replaces all spaces with a VB Line Feed (Return)